# Need help in report's dataset

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm using *iReport Professional 5.1.0*. I already used one query (some select query) in report query. But i need to use multiple queries in same report. So i tried with dataset. After creating dataset (Report Inspector -> right click Add Dataset), I've created different query. But i cant get any parameters (which is assigned to parent query column) to the newly created dataset.

My doubt is whether the dataset is applicable only to table, chart  and crosstabs. If no, then explain step by step procedure to use dataset in *iReport*.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters should be in each datasets so just copy the parameters from parent dataset and paste it in all the datasets and when you use any sub dataset for any chart, table or crosstables just pass all parameters and Expression for that parameter.